# MySQL and PHP on error parameter PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with my code I don't know why.

My code:

```
$al2ss = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM urun WHERE urunID = '".$urnListele['urunID']."' AND kategoriKod = '".$urnListele['kategoriKod']."' < 1 order by urunID DESC limit 1");
$al2sss = $al2ss->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
```

Comment: It's probably got something to do with `... AND kategoriKod = 'varhere' < 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tell database

```
kategoriKod = '".$urnListele['kategoriKod']."' < 1
```

It's something like say, in words, `select where this = that and that = 0` so that doesn't exist. This doesn't have so much sense, maybe you are looking for `that` if it doesn' exist so why don't you just go straight there?

```
kategoriKod != '".$urnListele['kategoriKod']."'
```

If you use `!=` it will be like comparing your actual value stored in variable against database and select where it doesn't exist

Comment: When I take one value there is no problem but I want to take more than one

Comment: I must send 2 value to take previous and next value

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
  AND kategoriKod = '".$urnListele['kategoriKod']."' < 1
```

either do this

```
  AND kategoriKod = '".$urnListele['kategoriKod']."'
```

or this

```
  AND kategoriKod  < 1
```

or you maybe need this

```
  AND kategoriKod = '".$urnListele['kategoriKod']."' AND kategoriKod < 1
```

i dont know what you really want to do.

Comment: Im taking sql data and I want to take previous and next sql data too

Comment: When I take one value there is no problem but I want to take more than one